# C - Pointer pointer as an argument

Tags: c, function, pointers, segmentation-fault

Accessing elements of a pointer pointer WITHIN a function after passing it as an argument causes my program to crash.

For example

INITIALIZATION:

```
edge **graph;
graph = malloc(e*sizeof(edge));
for(int i = 0; i< e;i++){
    graph[i] = malloc(sizeof(edge));
}
```

After initialization, this works:

```
printf("%d\n", graph[i]->cost);
```

But after passing it on to a function it crashes:

```
Function(edge **graph){
    //stuff
    printf("%d\n", graph[i]->cost); //this causes a crash
}
```

What's causing this? Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: `graph = malloc(e*sizeof(edge));` should be `graph = malloc(e*sizeof(*graph));` or `malloc(e*sizeof(edge*))`

Comment: You should post minimal and **complete** program that demonstrates the behaviour. You may be calling the function incorrectly.

Comment: Pointer Pointer?  I think u meant "Dual pointer"./ Pointer to pointer.

Comment: Or you may be corrupting the memory somewhere after intialisation and before the function call. So yes, agree with @user694733, please post a [Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @milevyo What do you mean? I simply asked OP to provide more details, as question in it's current form doesn't necessarily reveal the real problem. Others seem to agree, question is not clear enough yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`graph[i]` will be of type `edge *` (i.e. pointer to `edge`).

Generally speaking, `malloc()` should be used to allocate a multiple of the size being pointed to.    `graph` is of type `edge **`.   Which means the size supplied to `malloc()` should be a multiple of the size of an `edge *`.   Your code is allocating a multiple of `sizeof(edge)` which (unless you get lucky) is not equal to `sizeof(edge *)`.

Hence your `malloc()` call should look something like `graph = malloc(e * sizeof(edge *))` or (better, since it works out what `graph` points at without you having to scratch your head) `graph = malloc(e * sizeof(*graph))`.

If you don't do that, the result of using dereferencing `graph` (e.g. `graph[i]->cost` gives undefined behaviour.   Avoiding undefined behaviour is the reason you need to ensure (among other things) that the sizes allocated using `malloc()` are valid.   One symptom of undefined behaviour is a crash in some circumstances but not in others - such as you're seeing the same code doing different things in different contexts.